# How can i get the value from class="form-row" id="view" in selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, css, selenium, beautifulsoup

[image][![  My current code is running but i want alternative like any script in selenium using python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
all_text_tags = soup.find("div",{"id" :"view"})
labels_tag = all_text_tags.find_all("label")
count = 0
for i, j in zip(all_text_tags.find_all("input"), labels_tag):
    count += 1
    if i['value'] != "":
        print(i['value'])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `value` from **input** tag using `selenium`.

Use either of the css selector.

```
for inputtag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#view input"):
    print(inputtag.get_attribute("value"))
```

OR

```
for inputtag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#view [id^='input']"):
    print(inputtag.get_attribute("value"))
```

---

Get the value from label tag use below css selector

```
for labeltag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#view [id^='label']"):
    print(labeltag.text)
```

Comment: thank you so much could you please explain this code(("#view input"))?

Comment: @pycoderr : `#view` -select the element with the view Id. and `#view input` - DOM descendant combinator. All input tags that are a child of #view tags